# Fetch the body height of a person from IMDb

Tags: php, regex, imdb

I'm trying to fetch a persons body height from IMDb but the line for it contains a `#` which indicate a comment in PHP (for example `# The comment as follows`). Here is how it looks like from IMDb's source code:

```
<h4 class="inline">Height:</h4>
5' 7&#34; (1.70 m)
```

Here is my attempted regular expression:

`<h4 class="inline">Height:</h4>\n([0-9' &#;(.)m]+)`

What should I do to prevent it to comment the rest of the regular expression after the `#` character?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is the result from adding `\` to the regular expression:
[image]

Comment: [Take advice from here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Don't use RegEx. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ OR http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Paul: I want to use regular expression. Radix: Please see my image in my edited question. `\` didn't solve it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem and here is the answer:

`/<h4 class="inline">Height:<\/h4>\n([0-9\' ]+)&#34; ([0-9. m()]+)/`

Comment: drats! beat me by about a minute -- had it up on board. Congratulations a plus 1 for self sufficiency!